# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: fieldNameTranslator - but Solr indexes available and build successfully

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a new Sitecore 9.0.1 instance that I installed through SIF. It was installed using Lucene so I needed to install Solr and update the configuration. I went through the following steps to change it to use Solr: https://ericastockwellalpert.wordpress.com/2022/08/02/updating-a-sitecore-instance-to-use-solr-instead-of-lucene/

Solr is running and the indexes are able to build successfully. I initially had an issue with the Polish language processing where I needed to add some jars to Solr, but that seems to be resolved because the indexes build now without error (mentioning in case it's relevant). But I'm unable to open the content editor, I get the server error `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: fieldNameTranslator`

Comment: Looks like some lucene config files are still there on your server

Comment: Oh yes they are, do I need to delete all the Lucene configs?

Comment: @MarekMusielak I disabled every Lucene config file but am still getting the error

Comment: It depends on how they are configured. If all of them have "search:require=lucene" then not. Othwerise yes.

Comment: they do all have that, but I also disabled all Lucene configs. Still getting the error

Comment: Check if this article can help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46559324/sitecore-solr-index-fieldnametranslator-is-null

Comment: Can you check `ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress` in this `App_Config\Sitecore\ContentSearch\Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config` Config file. The solr URL is pointing to the right one? If in case you have multiple instances running.

Comment: It's https://localhost:8983 which is running

Comment: @EricaStockwell-Alpert And it is pointing to HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: The Solr configuration is fine. All indexes are showing in the control panel and build successfully so there's no issue with the solr address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that `Solr` was missing an expected index. The logs showed that `sitecore_suggested_test_index` was missing:

```
5312 16:11:56 ERROR Unable to connect to [https://localhost:8983/solr], Core: [sitecore_suggested_test_index]
Exception: SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException
Message: <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
```

To resolve the issue I disabled Content Testing by editing `Sitecore.ContentTesting.config` and setting `ContentTesting.AutomaticContentTesting.Enabled` to false